# How can I display a graph with 400 nodes from SQLalchemy

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, sqlalchemy

I want to display a graph with 400 or more nodes from `SQLalchemy`.

I have used `matplotlib` and `Networkx` but the problem is that I do not get clear and detectable nodes when their number exceed 100 and most times the nodes are over each other! What is the best way to display a graph with 400 clear and separate nodes from `SQLalchemy`?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a graph or how to display a graph?

Comment: @Joel, I need to know how to display the graph. 'Matplotlib' is not good to display a graph with more than 100 nodes.

Comment: I don't have a good solution.  This is always a challenging problem, and it depends heavily on the structure of the network.  If you can figure out yourself where each node should be located, then setting the `pos` variable in networkx will work.  But if your question is really about what algorithm to use to determine where the nodes go, then that's network dependent.  Some more information about the network?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your requirement, Sqlalchemy has nothing to do with displaying graph.
Even I had hard time with matplotlib.
Here is a brand new module which I discovered recently in pycon India.

https://plot.ly/python/  This library allows you to plot various charts using browser and also you will get a link to share with others.

Comment: I searched this website but I did not find a graph with nodes and edges. I need to generate a graph with directed edges to show the connection between different nodes.